# R Shiny has suddenly stopped rendering all tables and plots with no error message

Tags: r, shiny

I was developing a shiny app when suddenly all plots and tables stopped rendering. There was no error message so it was very confusing what the problem was. I want to share the answer the solution just in case anyone else runs into the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I had two downloadButton()s and linked them both to the outputId="dl". Not only did it stop everything from rendering but also gave HTML downloads called qwe_download